# localStorage for Radio Input?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have the following code working to remember my form input on page refresh. I'm not entirely sure how to progress with remembering the input for a radio button. How do adjust the code to do this?

```
<input type="radio" name="options[Substrate]" id="clear" class="substrate" value="Clear – 125 µm SU320" />
<input type="radio" name="options[Substrate]" id="white-50" class="substrate" value="White – 50 µm Melinex 339"/>


$(document).ready(function() {

// Save Order on Refresh
    $(window).unload(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();

});


function loadSettings() {
    $('#circuitsNum').val(localStorage.setcircuit);
    $('#distanceNum').val(localStorage.setdistance);
    $('#note').val(localStorage.setnote);
    $("#metreSelect").val(localStorage.setmetre);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.setcircuit = $('#circuitsNum').val();
    localStorage.setdistance = $('#distanceNum').val();
    localStorage.setnote = $('#note').val();
    localStorage.setmetre = $("#metreSelect").val();
}
```

Comment: save boolean for checkbox, $('#radiobutton').is(':checked') will give true/false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$('radioButton').prop("checked")` function to check if a radio button is selected.

and `$('radioButton').prop("checked", true)` to check a radio button.

Alternatively you can get the id of the checked option:

```
$('input[name="options[Substrate]"]:checked').attr('id')
```

To set values with localStorage use:

```
localStorage.setItem('item_key', 'item_value');
```

To get values from localStorage use:

```
localStorage.getItem('item_key');
```

So to use it with your code like so:

```
function saveSettings() {

    // Setting the ID of the checked button
    localStorage.setItem('substrateRadioButton', $('input[name="options[Substrate]"]:checked').attr('id'));

    // or

    // Setting the state of each button
    localStorage.setItem('clear', $("#clear").prop("checked")); 
    localStorage.setItem('white-50', $("#white-50").prop("checked")); 
}

function loadSettings () {
    // Gettings the ID of the checked button
    $("#"+localStorage.getItem('substrateRadioButton')).prop("checked", true);

    // or        

    // Gettings the state of each button
    $("#clear").prop("checked", localStorage.getItem('clear'));
    $("#white-50").prop("checked", localStorage.getItem('white-50'));
}
```

You can check if the value is set with an if statement:

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('item_key');

if (item) {
    // key is set
} else {
    // key is not set
}
```

It would be wise to check the existence of the values in your `loadSettings()` function.

Read more about `localStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

and more about `prop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).